# Python regular expressions - multiple occurrence

Tags: python, regex, list

How to find multiple occurrence of a pattern in a string and store all occurrences in a list as multiple elements.
for example:

```
re.search('[A-Z]+',"assAAhhhAB").group(0)
```

would give me :

```
AA
```

whereas I want output as

```
['AA' ,'AB']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
print(re.findall('[A-Z]+',"assAAhhhAB"))
# => ['AA', 'AB']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/MCukq5)